# How to show directory listing in alphabets to show directory in its Letter

Tags: php, directory-listing, alphabet

I have an array that already contains all it's values in alphabetical order:

Directory Listing:

```
Ahha
ah?
```

I just want to list the first letter each starts with above it like so:

```
A

___________________

Ahahhaa
Ah?
```

Like this

Here is code.

```
$alphabets = array('0-9','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z');

$letter = list of directory.

foreach ($alphabets as $alphabet) { 
if ($letter[$alphabet])
echo '<a href="#letter-'.$alphabet.'">'.$alphabet.'</a>  '; 
else 
echo $alphabet.'  ';  
}
```

I need to print directory list according to Alphabets.

```
<?php
foreach ($letter[$alphabet] as $name) {
   echo $name;  
}
?>

$letter[$alphabet] == return nothing.
```

php v5.5.5

Comment: Can you put up a sample `$letter` value too?

Comment: Updated post. Please check if its correct.

Comment: `if ($letter[$alphabet])` What is that statement expected to do?

Comment: replace your if to 
     
    if(isset($letter[$alphabet]) && $letter[$alphabet])

Comment: okay. Testing. Thanks for fast response.

Comment: if ($letter[$alphabet]) is =  $letter = directory lists array. Your code hide links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are trying to get this?

```
$alphabets = array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z');

$letter = array("Ahahah", "Bwahahah", "Ahow", "Catcw"); // is this what letters value?

foreach ($alphabets as $alphabet) {
  echo $alphabet;
  $match = null;
  foreach($letter as $let){
    preg_match("/[$alphabet]?/is", $let, $match);
    if(isset($match[0]) && $match[0]){
       echo '<a href="#letter-'.$alphabet.'">'.$let.'</a>  '; 
    }
  }
}
```

result:
    A Ahahaha Ahow B Bwahahah C Catcw

Comment: Its showing something. all together. after change the letter.

Comment: can you give me the sample value of $letter?

Comment: Thanks thats working after change the $letter. I can't rep+ you.

Comment: Its not printing 0-9 digit name. Also x alphabet showing no names.

Comment: Edited my answer.. try use it :)